# HtmlAgilityPack reading HTML in a wrong way?

Tags: c#, parsing, html-agility-pack

I have been using HAP for a pretty long time. And now I have a really simple question.
How to correctly load a webpage?

The reason I'm asking is because there is a website and a specific part in the formatting messes up with HAP:

```
<div class="like-bar">
    <div class="g-bar"><div class="green-bar" style="width:55.47%"/></div></div>
    <div class="like-descr">76 Likes, 61 Dislikes</div>
</div>
```

So the part I'm having the problem with is "`style="width:55.47%"/></div></div>`". So there is a closing tag for the g-bar class, a closing tag for the "green-bar" class, but the greenbar class by itself has the closing bracket (/>). As you could imagine, this screws up the whole formatting and makes it impossible to parse.

When I use inspect in any browser the "/>" tag is just not there. How can I figure out what writes it down? I download the page using the Load method from the HtmlWeb class.

**Update #1** 
For some really strange reason, the following does not work:

```
  <div class="like-bar">
        <div class="g-bar">
            <div class="green-bar" style="width:55.474452554745%"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="like-descr">
            <span class="bold">76</span><span>Likes</span>, <span class="bold">61</span><span>Dislikes</span>
        </div>
  </div>
```

The last  is not associated to the class like-bar, instead it links to a parent. 
What's wrong with this?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Browsers are being very forgiving. You need to look at the raw source to see where this is coming from (a self closing div is not valid HTML, which is where the parsing problem comes from, but browsers try to be forgiving about that).

Comment: Also not all browsers remove `/>` tag. E.g. with Opera it stays there. So, you have invalid HTML and *some* browsers can handle it

Comment: As I understood, if I just make some type of "clean up" methods to fix divs and other types of of invalid tags, i'll be good to go? 


P.S. Yes, Opera does not remove it, but seems to handle it just fine.